# I am getting "Method Not Implemented GET to xxx not supported" in a PUT cURL request

Tags: php, curl, request, put

I am setting CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT', and in my localhost server it works as expected. But in my web server i get the following message:

```
Method Not Implemented

GET to /web-services/index.php/attendance/user not supported.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I was using CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT'. And now I am using only curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT'));.